# Beginner having issues with Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to run the "Hello World" program in CMD  after writing the code in Notepad and saving it to a new file in my C Drive .And I keep getting the error message "access denied", when I try to run the program.

```
C:\>MyScripts>python hello.py
Access is denied.

C:\>
```

Using version 3.4.3 of the interpreter

Code:

```
print( "Hello World" )
```

I'm running Windows 8.1 on my laptop. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: whats the output of `python --version` ?

Comment: Please show us code :)

Comment: Probably you have no access rights to the Python interpreter itself. Was it installed by another user under his own account?

Comment: It was installed by me on my administrator account.

Comment: Judging by your screenshot, did you type `MyScripts >python hello.py`? There's your problem.

Comment: I just tried that, and I got the same error message.

Comment: So two things. 1. Where exactly is your `hello.py`? 2. Is `python` under your PATH. My guess is that `python` is already under your PATH and `hello.py` is at `C:\MyScript\hello.py` isn't it? So you can do either `cd \MyScript` then `python hello.py` or `cd \ ` then `python MyScripts\hello.py`

Comment: `MyScripts >python hello.py` was exactly where you made the mistake. `>` is [output redirection](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true), which I'm pretty sure isn't what you want.

Comment: The location of hello.py  (http://imgur.com/Ge1ragF) And I attempted both of your suggestions and here are the results.  1.  (http://imgur.com/aoQTVAo)   2. (http://imgur.com/qUXi9IH)

Comment: @Hybris Have you gone into folder options and [unchecked "Hide extensions"](http://fileinfo.com/images/help/win-folder-options-view.gif). If not then your file name is actually `hello.py.py`, because Windows hid its actual extension. While in `C:\MyScript`, run `dir` command and it will show you exactly what the file name is. Pro-tip, while in CMD (as well as most other shells) you can let it auto-fill by typing the first few letters of a file name then press tab key. eg. type `hel` then press tab.

Comment: You were right, so I remade the notepad document, and tried your first suggestion in the CMD. And it worked this time, thank you for your time and expertise.

Comment: @Hybris it's annoying to go to another link just to see a screenshot of a notepad with one line of text - please just copy&paste into the question next time (fixed the question text)

Answer (score 0):

You may change the word "python" with "C:\Python34\python

type the code exactly and it may work